# Keras - How to handle wave inputs of different length, split training data into batches

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, speech-to-text, mfcc

I am new to using Keras framework for implementing Neural Networks and I've also checked some very basic stuff about Tensorflow too.

I am trying to figure out how to split my training data (mfcc coeffs of .wav files) into batches to fit my model and also how to handle samples of different duration (and therefore of different shape in mfcc format).

I came across the following code snippet in Tensorflow but I cannot understand how it works in order to implement something similar in Keras. Any help either for "converting" the code to Keras logic or generally for my issues would be much appreciated. Thank you.

```
    label = [] # output label of each file 
    mfcc_file = [] # filenames of all .npy files containing mfcc coeffs

    # Load from corresponding files and fill in label, mfcc_file
    # .... 

    # to constant tensor
    label_t = tf.convert_to_tensor(label)
    mfcc_file_t = tf.convert_to_tensor(mfcc_file)

    # create queue from constant tensor
    label_q, mfcc_file_q \
        = tf.train.slice_input_producer([label_t, mfcc_file_t], shuffle=True)

    # create label, mfcc queue
    label_q, mfcc_q = self.load_mfcc([label_q, mfcc_file_q])

    # create batch queue with dynamic pad
    batch_queue = tf.train.batch([label_q, mfcc_q], batch_size,
                                 shapes=[(None,), (20, None)],
                                 num_threads=64, capacity=batch_size*32,
                                 dynamic_pad=True)

    # split data
    self.label, self.mfcc = batch_queue
    # batch * time * dim
    self.mfcc = self.mfcc.sg_transpose(perm=[0, 2, 1])
    # calc total batch count
    self.num_batch = len(label) // batch_size

    # print info
    tf.sg_info('%s set loaded.(total data=%d, total batch=%d)'
               % (set_name.upper(), len(label), self.num_batch))
```